# Question about allocating and releasing an object in a function

Tags: iphone, function, object, release

This is the code, it doesn't work when [unosUpisa release]; and [unosRazlike release]; are entered;

How to properly release those unosUpisa and unosRazlike objects?

```
-(IBAction) padIliStilja: (id) sender
{
    NSNumber *unosUpisa = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
    NSNumber *unosRazlike = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
    if ([sender tag] == 1)
    {
    unosUpisa = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 162 + [Data variables].zvanja];
    unosRazlike = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0];
    }
    else if ([sender tag] == 2)
    {
        unosRazlike = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 252 + [Data variables].zvanja];
        unosUpisa = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0];
    }

    if ([Data variables].upisZaMi == NO)
    {
        [[Data variables].rezultatMi addObject: unosUpisa];
        [[Data variables].rezultatVi addObject: unosRazlike];
    }
    else
    {
        [[Data variables].rezultatVi addObject: unosUpisa];
        [[Data variables].rezultatMi addObject: unosRazlike];
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: NO];
    [unosUpisa release];
    [unosRazlike release];
}
```

Comment: If you're going to reassign `unosUpisa`, and `unosRazlike` to a different, autoreleased variable, why initialize/allocate them sepearately to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `release` every object that you own (you retained, copied, or init/alloced).
The way you release your objects at the end is correct, **but**, here `unosRazlike = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0];`, you assigned `unosRazlike` another value, without releasing the previous one, and here is a leak.
Also, with this kind of method, you should retain your object.

So :

```
unosRazlike = ...
// first
[unosRazlike release];
unosRazlike = [[NSNumber numberWithInt: 0] retain];
// ...
[unosRazlike release];
```

**EDIT**

```
-(IBAction) padIliStilja: (id) sender
{
    // this is no matter
    NSNumber *unosUpisa = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
    NSNumber *unosRazlike = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
    if ([sender tag] == 1)
    {
        // don't forget to release them !
        [unosUpisa release]; [unosRazlike release];
        // and to retain (numberWithInt returns autoreleased object
        unosUpisa = [[NSNumber numberWithInt: 162 + [Data variables].zvanja] retain];
        unosRazlike = [[NSNumber numberWithInt: 0] retain];
    }
    else if ([sender tag] == 2)
    {
        // same again
        [unosUpisa release]; [unosRazlike release];
        // and to retain (numberWithInt returns autoreleased object
        unosRazlike = [[NSNumber numberWithInt: 252 + [Data variables].zvanja] retain];
        unosUpisa = [[NSNumber numberWithInt: 0] retain];
    }

    if ([Data variables].upisZaMi == NO)
    {
        [[Data variables].rezultatMi addObject: unosUpisa];
        [[Data variables].rezultatVi addObject: unosRazlike];
    }
    else
    {
        [[Data variables].rezultatVi addObject: unosUpisa];
        [[Data variables].rezultatMi addObject: unosRazlike];
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: NO];
    [unosUpisa release];
    [unosRazlike release];
}
```

But just a thought... why initializing 'blank' number objects, if you set the value either in the if or in the else part ?

Just declare them

```
NSNumber *unosRazlike, *unosUpisa;
```

and set their values in the if/else.

Comment: I tried to declare them at the beggining of the code as:
NSNumber *unosRazlike, *unosUpisa; but I get SIGABRT

Here is the code in pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/Z1GFiK0X

Comment: @Wikiboo - the mistakes are at lines 7/8, 12/13, `numberWithInt:` is class method ! use `initWithInt:` instead

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the calls before you dismiss the ViewController. It doesn't make much sense to release that memory when your ViewController is already being released.

Comment: Yep tried that to, that's way I tried to put it after the dismiss

Answer (score 0):

First you are dynamically allocating NSNumber then in your condition

```
if ([sender tag] == 1)
{
unosUpisa = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 162 + [Data variables].zvanja];
unosRazlike = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0];
}
else if ([sender tag] == 2)
{
    unosRazlike = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 252 + [Data variables].zvanja];
    unosUpisa = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0];
}
```

you are allocating NSNumber on the stack, thereby loosing the connection to the dynamically allocted NSNumber.

A better way would be to

```
if ([sender tag] == 1)
{
unosUpisa = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 162 + [Data variables].zvanja];
unosRazlike = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 0];
}
else if ([sender tag] == 2)
{
    unosRazlike = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 252 + [Data variables].zvanja];
    unosUpisa = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 0];
}
```

Comment: I've put NSNumber *unosUpisa; and NSNumber *unosRazlike; and then tried your code but I get an NSException

Comment: what does it say more specifically?

Comment: program receive signal "SIGABRT" and this is right nex to
unosRazlike = [[NSNumber alloc] numberWithInt: 252 + [Data variables].zvanja];

Comment: Are you sure you can access [Data variables].zvanja?

Comment: yes, It works in another files, here is the whole code:
http://pastebin.com/Z1GFiK0X

Comment: But can you access it in that file? Try to just print the value in the function. NSLog("%d", [Data variables].zvanja);

Answer (score 0):

Open your project in Xcode 4, go to the **Product** menu and select **Analyze**. Xcode will add blue annotation marks to your files with complete documentation for any memory management errors you may have within this method.

Read the warnings, fix them, and make sure you understand them for future reference.